# How do I stop the cloth modifier from treating a joined mesh as separate meshes?

Tags: mesh, blender-internal-render-engine, cloth-simulation

Is there any way to prevent get this to act as a single mesh? Also, I should note that it is pinned at the top.

[image: Joined Mesh Cloth Animation]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to make it act as a single mesh. The way to do it is to add appropriate vertices to vertical and horizontal bars in edit mode and join them.[image]